# how to force a long table begin in a new page, and fix the position?

Tags: longtable

I'm using the long table environment, and I want to start the table on top of a new page (otherwise it starts anywhere in my paper) and make the long table stay where I want it to be without being affected by the text. Is there any command I can use to achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: See the afterpage package.

Comment: `\clearpage` before the table would seem to be all you need.

Comment: @Mico see what the OP says but I understood the question to be rather the opposite and not wanting a floating table, we'll see....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The title of the old posting which I manage to dig up is actually quite misleading, at least in the way it's shown above. In the old posting, the OP used the term "floating" somewhat idiosyncratically, shall we say. For sure, the old posting is all about deferring the start of a `longtable` till the top of the next page. I've gone ahead and edited the title of the old posting to help clarify its purpose; however, this change isn't reflected in the hyperlink target shown above.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Issuing a `\clearpage` instruction immediately before `\begin{longtable}` will certainly succeed in making the table start at the top of the next page. It will also create a potentially huge "hole" at the bottom of the preceding page, right?

Comment: @Mico yes but that's what I understood as "without being affected by the text" . If you use `\afterpage` the position is certainly affected by the text. But anyway happy to wait for OP to comment, if `\clearpage` solves the issue I'll re-open:-)